# I want to show Word documents in Python program output

Tags: python, image-processing, file-handling

I have a few Word files which I want want to display in Python output. These Word files also contain multiple images. So how can I add them into the Python program for display?

I tried:

```
>>>from PIL import Image
```

but that gives image in other software hence not satisfying my demand.

Comment: I'm confused.lol

Comment: Nothing useful on Google: [search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&biw=1680&bih=869&ei=IMfAW-qTNMbGgAbZ3J2YAw&q=python+display+word+document)?. We help programmers to fix their code. Also `from PIL import Image` does not magically _"gives image in other software"_ so you must have written more than just one line of code for _"other software"_ to suddenly become involved. Also your shown code does not even try to use a `.doc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python **docx** module to read/display contents and images of word document.  Link for documentation below:

[Docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)